# Orphaned connections in CLOSE_WAIT state

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I've got a SLES machine that accumulates TCP connections in a CLOSE_WAIT state for what appears to be forever.  These descriptors eventually suck up all available memory.  At the moment, I've got 3037 of them, but it was much higher before a hurry-up reboot recently.

What's interesting is that they're not from connections to local ports that I expect to have listening processes.  They have no associated PIDs, and their timers seem to have expired.

```
# netstat -ton | grep CLOSE_WAIT
tcp      176      0 10.0.0.60:54882     10.0.0.12:31663      CLOSE_WAIT  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp       54      0 10.0.0.60:60957     10.0.0.12:4503       CLOSE_WAIT  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp       89      0 10.0.0.60:50959     10.0.0.12:3518       CLOSE_WAIT  off (0.00/0/0)

# netstat -tonp | grep CLOSE_WAIT
tcp       89      0 10.0.0.59:45598     10.0.0.12:1998       CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp       15      0 10.0.0.59:60861     10.0.0.12:1938       CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp        5      0 10.0.0.59:56173     10.0.0.12:1700       CLOSE_WAIT  -
```

I'm not a black-belt when it comes to the TCP stack, or kernel networking, but the TCP config seems sane, since these values are default, per the man page:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout 
60
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time 
7200
```

So what gives?  If the timers have expired, shouldn't the stack automatically clear this stuff out?  I'm effectively giving myself a long-term DoS as these things build up.

Comment: Oh, and my research shows that others are seeing artifacts like this in 'lsof -i'. I'm *not* seeing anything odd there.

Comment: Try `sudo netstat -tonp` to see which program this is occurring with.

Comment: The post and my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17697733/540323 will help.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355636/close-wait-tcp-states-despite-closed-file-descriptors

Answer (score 20):

No, there is no timeout for `CLOSE_WAIT`.  I think that's what the `off` means in your output.

To get out of `CLOSE_WAIT`, the application has to close the socket explicitly (or exit).

See [How to break CLOSE_WAIT](https://web.archive.org/web/20170113135705/http://unix.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/SunManagers/2006-01/msg00367.html).

If `netstat` is showing `-` in the process column:

- are you running with the appropriate privileges and capabilities (e.g. as root)?
- they could be kernel processes (e.g. nfsd)

Comment: When doing the netstats, I had full privs, yes.  I'll go check out the kernel processes angle -- that's a good idea.  I'm really stumped, because there aren't supposed to be any listening sockets at all, except for two or three well-known privileged ports.  Maybe it's a wierd iptables problem.  I'll check that out too.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Thanks, updated to http://unix.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/SunManagers/2006-01/msg00367.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me find a bug in my code that was causing CLOSE_WAIT!

Answer (score 11):

`CLOSE_WAIT` indicates that the client is closing the connection but the application hasn't closed it yet, or the client is not.  You should identify which program or programs are having this problem.  Try using

```
netstat -tonp 2>&1 | grep CLOSE
```

to determine which programs as holding the connections.

If there are no programs listed, then the service is being provided by the kernel.  These are likely RPC services such as `nfs` or `rpc.lockd`.  Listening kernel services can be listed with

```
netstat -lntp 2>&1 | grep -- -
```

Unless the RPC services have  been bound to fixed ports, they will bind to ephemeral ports as your connections appear to show.  You may also want to check the processes and mounts on the other server.

You may be able to bind your NFS services to fixed ports by doing the following:

1. Select four unused ports for NFS (32763-32766 used here)
2. Add fixed ports for NFS to `/etc/services`

   ```
   rpc.statd-bc    32763/udp                       # RCP statd broadcast
   rpc.statd-bc    32763/tcp
   rpc.statd       32764/udp                       # RCP statd listen
   rpc.statd       32764/tcp
   rpc.mountd      32765/udp                       # RPC mountd
   rpc.mountd      32765/tcp
   rpc.lockd       32766/udp                       # RPC lockd/nlockmgr
   rpc.lockd       32766/tcp
   ```
3. Configure statd to use the options `--port 32763 --outgoing-port 32764`
4. Configure rpcmountd to use the option `--port 32765`
5. Shutdown and restart NFS and RPC services.

Comment: I wrote that there were no PIDs, but didn't show my work.  I made a quick edit per your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @opboin: Added comments on ports without PIDS (kernel services).

Comment: CLOSE-WAIT means that the *peer* has closed its end and the local OS is waiting for the local application to close.

Answer (score 0):

While the [answer of Mikel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10132/100270) is likely also correct that kernel-side sockets like NFS can cause this, `CLOSE_WAIT  -` entries without associated FDs are more often:

Connections that were closed by the other side while they were in the local `listen()` queue before `accept()` could be called on them, see [my detailed answer with repro here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355636/close-wait-tcp-states-despite-closed-file-descriptors/77420709#77420709).

> in a CLOSE_WAIT state for what appears to be forever

They will stay in this state forever until you

- `accept()` them and then `close()` them, or
- `close()` the entire socket (that's probably less of a solution).

This is also explained in detail in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355636/close-wait-tcp-states-despite-closed-file-descriptors/77420709#77420709).

> These descriptors eventually suck up all available memory.

That should not happen, because as per `man 2 listen`, the length of the `listen()` queue is limited by

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog  # default 4096
/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn            # default 4096
```

unless, of course, you have multiple sockets you `listen()` on, as the above limits are per such socket.